# Silverlight tool kit accordion problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I  have installed silverlight 4 toolkit. It was told that there i can  find accordion by just using toolkit:Accordion.  But in my tool box i dont see the Accordion or when i manually write the code it gives me error and says that accordion is not found.

Some one please give me some best link where i can go through all available controls and use them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) to install the toolkit.  It will add all the required references and their dependencies.

You can look at the sample code for the [Controls Browser](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) to compare what namespaces are being referenced.

Comment: thats really awesome i am able to  see all controls now.